# How to chain in Javascript without Jquery?

Tags: javascript

When i search for answers for JS chaining, i get something like this which is j-query.

```
$("#wrapper").fadeOut().html("Welcome, Sir").fadeIn();
```

i want to know if there is any chaining method not related to j-query.
please.

Comment: You probably saw this tutorial due to your example. You should read further as it shows non-jquery chaining in javascript. http://javascriptissexy.com/beautiful-javascript-easily-create-chainable-cascading-methods-for-expressiveness/

Comment: It's up to you to write you code in such a way that your function invocations are chainable. You cannot chain arbitrary functions together, they need to be written specifically to support this, which most jQuery functions happen to be.

Comment: Granted that tutorial is not too good on closer inspection.

Comment: Any Javascript function that returns its own context (usually using `this`) can be chained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can organize chaining by returning context in methods, f.e.

```
var chaining = {
    do: function(){
        // code here...
        return this;
    },
    stuff: function(){
        // and here...
        return this;
    }
}
chaining.do().stuff()
```

Answer (score 2):

Chaining is possible because each method in jQuery returns a jQuery object. The initial call (the `$()`) creates a jQuery object. The rest are methods of jQuery that return a jQuery object. You can return the same instance or create a new one. In jQuery's case, they create new objects.

Here's a simple example of an object whose methods return itself.

```
function CustomObject(){
  if(!(this instanceof CustomObject)) return new CustomObject();
}

CustomObject.prototype.aMethod = function(){
  // do something
  return this;
}

CustomObject.prototype.anotherMethod = function(){
  // do something else
  return this;
}

// Use like
var a = CustomObject()
var b = a.aMethod().anotherMethod().anotherMethod();
a === b
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is. t is simple chain of responsibility design pattern.
Link to example:
http://www.dofactory.com/javascript/chain-of-responsibility-design-pattern

In a nutshell your methods must return this (ref to current object)

Answer (score 0):

Chaining is not a magic,if the returned element is or subset of the initial object set then only chaining is applied. Thus you can't use $("#wrapper").fadeOut().html().fadeIn();

because when you use this .html() version m then the returned element is not an jquery object so the chain breaks. It is same for javascript.